# How to Convert server Image url into Drawable Int

Tags: android

I have images in server and am loading it into android app using Picasso library, I want to ZoomIn and Zoom Out all loaded images in app.
I referred https://developer.android.com/training/animation/zoom#java this link to Enlarge imageView.

In this below code while calling **zoomImageFromThumb** , they are passing ImageView holder and Drawable int

Please help me to **Convert Image URl to Drawable Int** to pass as a parameter and also please let me know if any other solution is there.

Thanks in advance

Loading images code

```
Picasso.get()
.load(model.getImage_path())
        .error(R.drawable.not_found)
        .into(image_IV)
```

Calling zoomImageFromThumb

`````
        thumb1View.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                zoomImageFromThumb(thumb1View, R.drawable.image1);
            }
        });````
`````

Comment: Server Image cannot convert Drawable Int. It can convert to BitmapDrawable. Drawable Int is used for resource of application. resource is cannot changed dynamic.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel.Wang , If it is not possible Please tell me how can i zoom In and Zoom out images... Is there any other way to achieve this..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are taking `drawableId` as `Int` and setting it as `image` inside `ImageView` but in your case you can use `picasso` to load `image` into `Imageview`, so you can just pass the `url` instead of `drawableId` into `zoomImageFromThumb` method like below

```
 private fun zoomImageFromThumb(thumbView: View, imageUrl: String) {
        // If there's an animation in progress, cancel it
        // immediately and proceed with this one.
        currentAnimator?.cancel()

        //load image using picasso
        Picasso.get()
        .load(imageUrl)
        .error(R.drawable.not_found)
        .into(findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.expanded_image))
    
        // Calculate the starting and ending bounds for the zoomed-in image.
        // This step involves lots of math. Yay, math.
        val startBoundsInt = Rect()
        val finalBoundsInt = Rect()
        val globalOffset = Point()
    
        // The start bounds are the global visible rectangle of the thumbnail,
        // and the final bounds are the global visible rectangle of the container
        // view. Also set the container view's offset as the origin for the
        // bounds, since that's the origin for the positioning animation
        // properties (X, Y).
        thumbView.getGlobalVisibleRect(startBoundsInt)
        findViewById<View>(R.id.container)
                .getGlobalVisibleRect(finalBoundsInt, globalOffset)
        startBoundsInt.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y)
        finalBoundsInt.offset(-globalOffset.x, -globalOffset.y)
    
        val startBounds = RectF(startBoundsInt)
        val finalBounds = RectF(finalBoundsInt)
    
        // Adjust the start bounds to be the same aspect ratio as the final
        // bounds using the "center crop" technique. This prevents undesirable
        // stretching during the animation. Also calculate the start scaling
        // factor (the end scaling factor is always 1.0).
        val startScale: Float
        if ((finalBounds.width() / finalBounds.height() > startBounds.width() / startBounds.height())) {
            // Extend start bounds horizontally
            startScale = startBounds.height() / finalBounds.height()
            val startWidth: Float = startScale * finalBounds.width()
            val deltaWidth: Float = (startWidth - startBounds.width()) / 2
            startBounds.left -= deltaWidth.toInt()
            startBounds.right += deltaWidth.toInt()
        } else {
            // Extend start bounds vertically
            startScale = startBounds.width() / finalBounds.width()
            val startHeight: Float = startScale * finalBounds.height()
            val deltaHeight: Float = (startHeight - startBounds.height()) / 2f
            startBounds.top -= deltaHeight.toInt()
            startBounds.bottom += deltaHeight.toInt()
        }
    
        // Hide the thumbnail and show the zoomed-in view. When the animation
        // begins, it will position the zoomed-in view in the place of the
        // thumbnail.
        thumbView.alpha = 0f
        expandedImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    
        // Set the pivot point for SCALE_X and SCALE_Y transformations
        // to the top-left corner of the zoomed-in view (the default
        // is the center of the view).
        expandedImageView.pivotX = 0f
        expandedImageView.pivotY = 0f
    
        // Construct and run the parallel animation of the four translation and
        // scale properties (X, Y, SCALE_X, and SCALE_Y).
        currentAnimator = AnimatorSet().apply {
            play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    expandedImageView,
                    View.X,
                    startBounds.left,
                    finalBounds.left)
            ).apply {
                with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top, finalBounds.top))
                with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale, 1f))
                with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale, 1f))
            }
            duration = shortAnimationDuration.toLong()
            interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
            addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                    currentAnimator = null
                }
    
                override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
                    currentAnimator = null
                }
            })
            start()
        }
    
        // Upon clicking the zoomed-in image, it should zoom back down
        // to the original bounds and show the thumbnail instead of
        // the expanded image.
        expandedImageView.setOnClickListener {
            currentAnimator?.cancel()
    
            // Animate the four positioning/sizing properties in parallel,
            // back to their original values.
            currentAnimator = AnimatorSet().apply {
                play(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.X, startBounds.left)).apply {
                    with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.Y, startBounds.top))
                    with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_X, startScale))
                    with(ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(expandedImageView, View.SCALE_Y, startScale))
                }
                duration = shortAnimationDuration.toLong()
                interpolator = DecelerateInterpolator()
                addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
    
                    override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                        thumbView.alpha = 1f
                        expandedImageView.visibility = View.GONE
                        currentAnimator = null
                    }
    
                    override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
                        thumbView.alpha = 1f
                        expandedImageView.visibility = View.GONE
                        currentAnimator = null
                    }
                })
                start()
            }
        }
    }
```